# this.own not defined in Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm trying to create a singleton class in Dojo with a method called loadsth. There I want o run this.own from within a foreach loop. However, when I run this code it says

```
TypeError: this.own is not a function
```

I looked into the Dojo docs and scripts and there it says that the method "own" is part of dijit/Destroyable. But although it is included it doesn't work. I tried it at the positions //@1 and //@2. I actually need it at position //@2 but wanted to make sure that the foreach loop doesn't hide "this". So I tried //@1 but this doesn't work as well.

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dijit/Destroyable"    
], function (
    declare,
    destroyable
) {
    var SingletonClass = declare("some.Class", null, {

        _registerdPropertyGrids: [],
        _resourceNode: "",

        /*
         * This method is used register a property grid plus
         * provide the properties that should be shown in that 
         * grid. 
         */
        registerWidget: function(widgetName, propertyGridWidget) {
            console.log(widgetName);
            this._registerdPropertyGrids.push({widgetName, propertyGridWidget});
        },

        /*
         * Sets the resource node for this widget.
         */
        setResourceNode: function(resourceNode) {
            this._resourceNode = resourceNode;
        },

        /*
         * Loads sth.
         */
        loadSth: function() {
            console.log("load");
            //var deferred = this.own(...)[0]; // @1
            this._registerdPropertyGrids.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
                console.log('_registerdPropertyGrids[' + index + '] = ' + element.widgetName);

                var deferred = this.own(...)[0]; // @2
            }, this);
        }
    });
    if (!_instance) {
        var _instance = new SingletonClass();
    }
    return _instance;
});
```

I suppose it has something todo with the implementation of the single class.

So my actual question is: Why does it say that this.own is not defined when I have dijit/Destroyable in the dependency list of "define"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `dijit/Destroyable` listed as a dependency but you're not actually making your declared constructor extend from it, and as a result your own prototype doesn't have `own` on it.

Instead of `declare("...", null, {`, you want `declare(destroyable, {` (where `destroyable` is replacing `null`).

Notes:

- The string argument to declare is deprecated, as it populates a global namespace, which is discouraged with AMD.
- I would recommend renaming `destroyable` to `Destroyable`.  Common convention is for constructors to start with a capital letter.

Comment: Is there a link/document where I can find the dojo conventions? I've been searching for this but couldn't find anything.

Comment: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/developer/styleguide.html#developer-styleguide lists the conventions for Dojo 1.x; https://github.com/SitePen/.jshintrc lists conventions used for dgrid 0.4, dstore, Intern, and future packages.